# m.one + m.two + m.three doesn't work

Tags: ruby, return, null

This is my code:

```
class Person
  def initialize(first_name, last_name, age)
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name = last_name
    @age = age
  end

  def first_name
    puts @first_name
  end

  def last_name
    puts @last_name
  end

  def age
    puts @age
  end
end

class Musician < Person
  def initialize(first_name, last_name, age, instrument)
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name = last_name
    @age = age
    @instrument = instrument
  end

  def instrument
    puts @instrument
  end
end
```

Then when I try to do the following:

```
m = Musician.new("George", "Harrison", 58, "guitar")
m.first_name + " " + m.last_name + ": " + m.age.to_s
```

I get an error:

> in `<main>': undefined method`+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Why can't I just concatenate the results of objects method?

Comment: A function named last_name meant to return last name is printing last_name to the console not returning anything out.

Btw, try reading error, its English, it says either first_name(mostly) or last_name is nil. You could have a instance method for Musician say display_name, returning "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}: #{self.age}".

Answer (score 3):

all your methods return nil rather than the value you wish, that is, "puts" returns nil. 
just eliminate the "puts" and try again

Comment: If I eliminate puts. It returns nothing. Maybe something like this: print @first_name?

Comment: @AlexDvoretskiy: You want `def first_name; @first_name; end` or just use [`attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) and friends define the methods for you.

Comment: I don't know why but 
  
def get_name 
     return @myname 
end 

Doesn't work!!! I can't see the result.

Comment: @AlexDvoretskiy.. If you want concatenated result, you should be doing `puts m.first_name + " " + m.last_name + ": " + m.age.to_s` in the last name..