# + is an undefined method after using super to call parent variables

Tags: ruby

This is a follow up from [Creating a class which inherits from another class in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092884/creating-a-class-which-inherits-from-another-class-in-ruby) and [m.one + m.two + m.three doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944555/m-one-m-two-m-three-doesnt-work). We are applying for [App Academy](http://www.hashmaplabs.com/app_academy/code_test) which is a Learn to Code course for people with little or no experience. As a result, these questions are similar, but I felt the answers in the other two posts did not address an answer, but diverged to explaining tangential concepts (which I did utilize)

To follow up on the first two mentioned links, I am having a problem with inherited classes. I have the Musician class which is inheriting three variables from the Person class. My problem is that when I run the

```
m.first_name + " " + m.last_name + ": " + m.age.to_s
```

I get an error: person.rb:31: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError). I understand that this error has the answer, but I am not yet adept at understanding what this means.

One point to mention is that the query above, must be the way it is. I can not put Puts in front of it.

I would appreciate any suggestions as to why I am getting this statement regarding + being an undefined method.

Thanks!

edit: Thanks for the quick response. I didnt realize the coding community was so active! This is really amazing. I am going to edit the code to reflect the newest issues, so I dont keep getting the same suggestions.

Comment: Ugh; tabs. Makes things difficult. Let the holy war begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get an error: person.rb:31: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError). I understand that this error has the answer, but I am not yet adept at understanding what this means.

It means that one of the three variables is `nil`, i.e., it lacks a value:

```
m.first_name
m.last_name
```

This is occurring because you are returning the result of calling the `puts` function in all of your accessors.  You need to return the variables themselves, not print them and return the result *of the print function*.

Also, since you are already using `attr_reader` you have `get` methods created for you already.  That's the whole point of using `attr_reader`; it creates a function which returns an underlying instance variable for you, you simply need to initialize it.

for example, this:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    @bar
  end
end
```

is equivalent to

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :bar
end
```

Comment: @DaveNewton: Haha I noticed something I missed at first glance... multiple times.

Comment: @EdS. Oh wow- Thank you for explaining the attr_reader. I removed the receptivity. One thing I still dont understand is, how do I get the: m = Musician.new("George", "Harrison", 58, "guitar")
m.first_name + " " + m.last_name + ": " + m.age.to_s
m.instrument
to print?

Comment: @LKBGIFT See the [attr_reader](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_reader) docs--I urge against using functionality at random!

Comment: @DaveNewton : / I will not make that mistake again. I read through, but it wasn't understandable to me at this point. A key point to always consider- : )

Comment: @LKBGIFT: In a 'real' application you would probably not have a `puts` inside of a getter method like that, and you certainly would not return what `puts` returns. If you want to print the variables do so externally, not from within the method itself.

Comment: Meh. Logging, even using `puts`, is a tried-and-true means of quick-and-dirty exploration, especially for people not familiar with ruby-debug or pry, and most new devs aren't IMO.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I knew I would regret that "never"... I meant only that it is common for a beginner to do something like that to get an understanding of what is happening, less common to see in a real-world application.  Of course there are reasons to do so as you say.

Comment: @DaveNewton I feel like I missed out on some comment before it was edited.

Comment: @LKBGIFT: I originally said in a previous comment that " In a 'real' application you would **never** have a puts inside of a getter method like that."  That is wrong.  You wouldn't return whatever `puts` returned, but you may well use it for logging or debugging purposes.  The problem with your code is that you are returning whatever `puts` returns instead of returning the variable. If you want to print it out that's ok, but you should have `def first_name; puts(@first_name); return @first_name; end`

Comment: @EdS. Gotcha- So Im not only printing, but Im also returning it. I will try this out. I just realized that my understanding of returning is very different- Thanks again-

Comment: @LKBGIFT: Yes.  Sans the presence of an earlier, explicit `return` statement, the last result of the last expression in a method will be returned to the caller.  So you are returning whatever `puts` returned, which happens to be `nil`.

Comment: @EdS. I made the changes to my code above, based on what I believed would work. Instead of printing the 

m.first_name + " " + m.last_name + ": " + m.age.to_s

It simply lists out the four arguments in Musician. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: @LKBGIFT: It lists out the four variable values because you have a `puts` in each getter.  It *then* proceeds to show you the return value of the expression `m.first_name + " " + m.last_name + ": " + m.age.to_s` assuming you are running in `irb`.  If this is a script in a file then yes, your expression will not be displayed because you have not called a function to display it. It is evaluated and the return value discarded.  Wrap anything you want to print in a `puts()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your accessors are returning the results of `puts`, not the instance variable's values.

First, you're already using `attr_reader`, which generates those methods *for* you.

Second, `first_name`, for example, should just return `@first_name`:

```
def first_name
  @first_name
end
```

Comment: Got it- So I removed the puts and focus on using the attr_reader. Now my issue is that I dont know how to get a non-Puts variable to print in the requests below. Its an odd situation, because I need to use the query 
m = Musician.new("George", "Harrison", 58, "guitar")
m.first_name + " " + m.last_name + ": " + m.age.to_s

m.instrument

Comment: @LKBGIFT I don't quite understand what you mean (and it's not a "query"). Without knowing specifically what you're trying to do it's difficult to help.

Comment: @LKBGIFT If you're talking about the code at the bottom of that page you link to, they're running code inside `irb` (or `repl.it`, etc) and evaluating immediate expressions. If you want to see those values from inside a script file you *need* to use `puts`.

Comment: @DaveNewton My problem is that I need to have the code ad the bottom display: You should then make a Musician class which inherits from the Person class. You should be able to do the following:

  > m = Musician.new("George", "Harrison", 58, "guitar")
  > m.first_name + " " + m.last_name + ": " + m.age.to_s
  => "George Harrison: 58"
  > m.instrument
  => "guitar"

When I use the puts in the methods, as I had done before, the variables come back nil...

Comment: @LKBGIFT But you're doing it wrong, as I said. You either need to (a) evaluate it immediately from the repl (irb, repl.it, whatever), or use `puts` in the script file. You're focusing too much on making something look exactly like something else rather than learning what it's trying to teach you.

Comment: @DaveNewton (i laughed at "you're doing it wrong") 
okay. Im stuck because the instructions of this question is asking for the output of the code to be what I mentioned above.

Comment: @DaveNewton In any case, thanks for your help- I need to review the replies I got to really understand what you are saying.